# redirect .aspx to Wordpress postname on a Microsoft IIS server (using web.config)

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I'd like to redirect

```
www.example.com/category/product.aspx
```

to

```
www.example.com/category/product
```

and

```
www.example.com/page.aspx
```

to

```
www.example.com/page
```

on a Microsoft IIS server using `web.config`.

I am a complete IIS novice, help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want this redirect specifically for this two links? Or you want to apply it for all links?

Comment: All links thanks @VictorLeontyev.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all you need to install URL rewrite module for IIS.

1) Install URL rewrite https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2) In your `web.config` add rule

```
<rule name="Redirect aspx to non-aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*).aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

(this rule should be in sections -> `configuration -> system.webServer -> rewrite -> rules` if you don't have this sections, then you need to create it)